# vectorized sum of interpolated values over many arrays

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, vectorization

I have a large set (thousands) of smooth lines (series of x,y pairs) with different sampling of x and y and different length for each line, i.e.

```
x_0 = {x_00, x_01, ..., }  # length n_0
x_1 = {x_10, x_11, ..., }  # length n_1
...
x_m = {x_m0, x_m1, ..., }  # length n_m

y_0 = {y_00, y_01, ..., }  # length n_0
y_1 = {y_10, y_11, ..., }  # length n_1
...
y_m = {y_m0, y_m1, ..., }  # length n_m
```

I want to find cumulative properties of each line interpolated to a regular set of x points, i.e. `x = {x_0, x_1 ..., x_n-1}`

Currently I'm `for`-looping over each line, creating an interpolant, resampling, and then taking the sum/median/whatever of that result.  It works, but it's really slow.  **Is there any way to vectorize / matrisize this operation?**

I was thinking, since linear interpolation can be a matrix operation, perhaps it's possible.  At the same time, since each row can have a different length... it might be complicated.  *Edit: but zero padding the shorter arrays would be easy...*

---

What I'm doing now looks something like,

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.interpolate

...

# `xx` and `yy` are lists of lists with the x and y points respectively
# `xref` are the reference x values at which I want interpolants
yref = np.zeros([len(xx), len(xref)])
for ii, (xi, yi) in enumerate(zip(xx, yy)):
    yref[ii] = sp.interp(xref, xi, yi)

y_med = np.median(yref, axis=-1)
y_sum = np.sum(yref, axis=-1)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, you can adjust the following for your purposes.

I included pandas because it has an interpolation feature to fill in missing values.

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(19)
x_0 = x[::2]
x_1 = x[::3]

np.random.seed([3,1415])
y_0 = x_0 + np.random.randn(len(x_0)) * 2
y_1 = x_1 + np.random.randn(len(x_1)) * 2

xy_0 = pd.DataFrame(y_0, index=x_0)
xy_1 = pd.DataFrame(y_1, index=x_1)
```

Note:

- `x` is length 19
- `x_0` is length 10
- `x_1` is length 7

`xy_0` looks like:

```
            0
0   -4.259448
2   -0.536932
4    0.059001
6    1.481890
8    7.301427
10   9.946090
12  12.632472
14  14.697564
16  17.430729
18  19.541526
```

`xy_0` can be aligned with `x` via `reindex`

```
xy_0.reindex(x)

            0
0   -4.259448
1         NaN
2   -0.536932
3         NaN
4    0.059001
5         NaN
6    1.481890
7         NaN
8    7.301427
9         NaN
10   9.946090
11        NaN
12  12.632472
13        NaN
14  14.697564
15        NaN
16  17.430729
17        NaN
18  19.541526
```

we can then fill in missing with `interpolate`

```
xy_0.reindex(x).interpolate()

            0
0   -4.259448
1   -2.398190
2   -0.536932
3   -0.238966
4    0.059001
5    0.770445
6    1.481890
7    4.391659
8    7.301427
9    8.623759
10   9.946090
11  11.289281
12  12.632472
13  13.665018
14  14.697564
15  16.064147
16  17.430729
17  18.486128
18  19.541526
```

What about `xy_1`

```
xy_1.reindex(x)

            0
0   -1.216416
1         NaN
2         NaN
3    3.704781
4         NaN
5         NaN
6    5.294958
7         NaN
8         NaN
9    8.168262
10        NaN
11        NaN
12  10.176849
13        NaN
14        NaN
15  14.714924
16        NaN
17        NaN
18  19.493678
```

Interpolated

```
xy_0.reindex(x).interpolate()

            0
0   -1.216416
1    0.423983
2    2.064382
3    3.704781
4    4.234840
5    4.764899
6    5.294958
7    6.252726
8    7.210494
9    8.168262
10   8.837791
11   9.507320
12  10.176849
13  11.689541
14  13.202233
15  14.714924
16  16.307842
17  17.900760
18  19.493678
```

Comment: +1, this is really cool and useful.  But it doesn't answer the question *per se* about vectorizing the process --- I have thousands of `x` and `y` arrays, which I'd like to process together.  I've edited the question to make that more clear (sorry if it wasn't previously).